# Creating a CSR x.509 in python

Tags: python, x509certificate2, csr

I'm creating this CSR but there's an error shows I don't know how to solve.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID, ExtensionOID

# Generate a private key
private_key = dsa.generate_private_key(key_size=2048)

# Set the subject name and add extensions
subject = x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, "SA"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, "TEST ORG"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, "219222"),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, "IOI"),
])
extensions = [
    x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
    x509.KeyUsage(digital_signature=True, key_encipherment=True, content_commitment=False, data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False),
    x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        x509.DirectoryName(x509.Name([
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.SERIAL_NUMBER, "Device1"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.USER_ID, "1111"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.TITLE, "CER"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.REGISTERED_ADDRESS, "ADDRESS"),
            x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.BUSINESS_CATEGORY, "TECH"),
        ]))
    ]),
    x509.CertificatePolicies([
        x509.PolicyInformation(x509.ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2"), [])
    ])
]

# Generate the CSR
csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(subject).add_extensions(extensions).sign(private_key, hashes.SHA256())

# Save the CSR and private key to files
with open("csr_testo.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(csr.public_bytes(encoding=x509.Encoding.PEM))

with open("private_key_testo.pem", "wb") as f:
    f.write(private_key.private_bytes(encoding=x509.Encoding.PEM, format=x509.PrivateFormat.PKCS8, encryption_algorithm=x509.NoEncryption()))
```

And this is the error that shows while I'm run the code:

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: KeyUsage.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'key_cert_sign' and 'crl_sign'
```

Let me know if there any other good idea or it's good to do it in this way.

Comment: The error message tells you that you need to supply two more parameters when creating the `KeyUsage` object: you can see the meaning of those parameters in the documentation at https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.KeyUsage

Comment: Thank you! it worked but there is another error if you could solve it, I edit the question.

Comment: For the meaning of the missing parameter in the error message see: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder.add_extension